# Ubuntu cant create bower_components folder

Tags: ubuntu, bower, bower-install

I am currently learning angular, and now im using the official angular tutorial by google. One thing that bothers me is that I cant get the bower_components to be created inside of my working projct folder. I circumvented this problem by providing a cdn link to bootstrap and angular, but for some reason this doesnt work for the angular-router-ui link.

When I try to install bower I get this error

```
bower EACCES        EACCES, mkdir '/home/johan/angular-phonecat/app/bower_components'

Stack trace:
Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/johan/angular-phonecat/app/bower_components'

Console trace:
Trace
    at StandardRenderer.error (/home/johan/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:72:17)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/home/johan/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:111:22)
    at Logger.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Logger.emit (/home/johan/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /home/johan/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:40:20
    at _rejected (/home/johan/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
    at /home/johan/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (/home/johan/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/johan/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
    at /home/johan/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44

System info:
Bower version: 1.3.7
Node version: 0.10.25
OS: Linux 3.13.0-30-generic x64
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
johan@johan-desktop:~/angular-phonecat$ ls
app  bower.json  LICENSE  node_modules  package.json  README.md  scripts  test
johan@johan-desktop:~/angular-phonecat$ cd app
johan@johan-desktop:~/angular-phonecat/app$ ls
css  img  index.html  js  partials  phones
johan@johan-desktop:~/angular-phonecat/app$ sudo npm install
[sudo] password for johan: 
npm WARN cannot run in wd angular-phonecat@0.0.0 bower install (wd=/home/johan/angular-phonecat)
johan@johan-desktop:~/angular-phonecat/app$
```

As you can see, it refused to create the bower_components folder in /app/ that I need. How to fix this? Im no ubuntu expert.

edit: The tutorial assumes that bower creates this folder inside my working folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
```

And as you can see in the console above, ubuntu refused to make that folder. How do I get ubuntu to create that folder?

edit2: angular-ui-router differs from angular-router, so now my workaround works perfectly. But still Im interested in the /bower_components/ folder.

Comment: not really related to angularJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you cannot write to a directory or file, you are facing permission issues which is a result of wrong owner handling the files.

Check if your app folder is owned by you (in our case it is you, 'johan')

use the command `ls -l` from the parent of your app folder and check if you own the file.
If you are not the owner of the file then use the below command to gain ownership of the file

```
chown -R johan:johan app
```

**Note:** This is an apt solution for this scenario as the home directory should be owned by the user. *Do not change ownership of system folders or files*, they will cause complex problems.

Comment: Thanks, but I cant give acces to a folder that does not exist. The problem is that ubuntu does not create that folder, but it should when i type npm install according to the tutorial. As you can see in the console above, there is an error creating the folder --> Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/johan/angular-phonecat/app/bower_components'

Comment: @sheez use "ls -l" in terminal and check the ownership of the app folder. If the ownership is anything other than johan use "chown -R johan:johan app" then try running npm install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I solved it. I do not know, why there is not this information in the angular tutorial (phonecat), but this may help.

install globally:

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

then go to your project folder:

```
cd .../angular-phonecat
```

and install directly:

```
bower install
```

All the necessary directories, must be in place.